# How to connect Mysql usign Intellij Idea

Tags: java, mysql, macos, intellij-idea

I'm learning java and I'm trying to connect mySql database with Intellij Idea.

I downloaded mysql and mysql workbench. Also , i downloaded "mysql connection jar". And i add the jar from modules section.

My code and the error :  https://prnt.sc/rchbuo

Mysql workbench server info : https://prnt.sc/rchcm6

Everything seems OK. But i get error. Do you have a suggestion ?

Comment: You have a message in your console, saying *No suitable driver found for ...*. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2839563/6908551

Comment: Please post code as text inside the question.

Comment: Anyway, why do you have a `tar` file in your external libraries?

Comment: @Federico , because i’m new to macos and mysql. I add the tar file to external libraries. I also add to the modules..

Comment: That has nothing to do with either MacOs or MySQL. Java libraries are in jar files, which that tar probably contains. So that's what you should import in your project.

Answer (score 1):

The way Java works, external modules are  `.jar` files. Here's a [guide to installing the MySQL java module, branded Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-binary-installation.html). Try extracting the contents of your `mysql-connector-java.8.0.19.tar` file. It contains the `.jar` file you need as an external module..

This is definitely baffling to Java newcomers.  `.jar` files are basically `.zip` files with a standardized set of stuff in them.  The whole Java system knows how to treat them as code modules.  `.tar` files, on the other hand, are a kind of multifile archive that originated with UNIX. Java treats them as plain old files (that is, ignores them).

Patience! You'll get the knack!